# How to get data from one worksheet to another programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I am trying to populate or get the data from following table in excel to another table. I want to write code in excel VB to do the following :

1. Search the first col JOB -->find the job name
2. Search the third col HOUR -->find the hour
3. According to the job name and hour get the value Col GCP_SECS for correct job and hour
4. put the value into anoher table .

I have no experience on Execel VB , really need someone to help me with this .
Thanks for your help!

```
JOB           DATE      HOUR GCP_SECS
GEMAB1PV      8/17/2015 12   1021.42
GEMAB1PV      8/17/2015 13   862.24
GEMAB1PV      8/17/2015 14   269.18
GEMAB7PV      8/17/2015 14   671.87
GEMAB7PV      8/17/2015 15   1034.24
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect candidate for Index/Match (the "extended" type too, using two lookups and entering as Array - good stuff!)

[image]

NOTE: Enter that formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

So, if you have two cells that have a Job Name and another with Hour (in my screenshot, this is G3 and H3.  Use those as your `Match()` requirements, and then use where they appear in your table as the `Match()` ranges (note the use of `&` to connect the two).  And, since you want to return the `GCP_SECS` info, use D2:D6 as the `Index()` range.

Does this make sense? You can enter the Index/Match formula on any page.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfect !

Comment: I recommend taking the time to get to know `Index/Match`, it's quite powerful (especially when compared to its better known cousin `Vlookup`).  Glad to hear it worked! (Do you mind marking as the answer?)

Comment: One more question , why we need Enter that formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. This formula does not work without this , don't know why ?  Another question is that when you have one cell is set up , you drag that cell down to next few cell vertically , the formula is automatically set up for all other cell.What if the cell i want to fill in (GCP_SECS) is not in col order is in row (not vertically but horizontally ), if you drag the cell to the right , it will not change proper cell as you darg down, what the correct way to do that ?  Thanks !!

Comment: You need `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` because it's being entered as an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).  If you want to drag horizontally, you'll have to edit the code a little, and edit where the lookup info is.  How is your table set up, so you want to drag right?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below vlookup function with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for this:

```
=LEFT(VLOOKUP(J4&K4,C3:H7&F3:F7,6,0),LEN(VLOOKUP(J4&K4,C3:H7&F3:F7,6,0))-2)
```

see the below pic for more clarification:

[image]

Good Luck :)